# java Generics legacy compitability problem

Tags: java, generics

this code compiles fine and when executed produce "004b" how that happen why it do not produce an classcastException.

```
public static void append(List list) {
    list.add("004b");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    append(intList);
    System.out.println(intList.get(0));
}
```

Comment: I would not say it compiles fine - the compiler should give you a warning on the use of a raw List type. If you don't heed that warning, well, you're the programmer :)

Answer (score 4):

Suggestions:

1. Don't mix raw and generic typing
2. Turn on your Java compiler's generic type
   warnings.  That will tell you about your unsound code.
3. If you use a "checked collection" type (e.g. as created using Collections.checkedList(...)) you will get an exception when you insert an incorrectly typed object into the collection.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling the `System.out.println(Object)` override since the type of `intList.get(0)` is `Integer` and there is no `Integer`-specific overload. After compilation the type information is erased, leaving a return type of simply `Object` for `intList.get(0)` after type erasure. That matches the expected type for the `println(Object)` function call so there is no runtime casting done, and no exception thrown.

Comment: If the type of `intList` was `List<char[]>` an exception would have been thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Because generics are implemented in Java via type-erasure; that is, there is no runtime information about the types, just casts where appropriate.  If you were to say

```
Integer i = intList.get(0);
```

then it would compile to

```
Integer i = (Integer) intList.get(0);
```

and throw a class cast exception.

Since System.out.println() takes an Object as an argument, no casting is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you expecting a ClassCastException to happen?

It won't happen when you call append, because append uses a raw List.

It won't happen when you call println, because println takes an Object, and so no implicit casting is done.

It might be a bit surprising that the overload resolution picks println(Object) rather than println(int) (because that overload does exist). This is because autoboxing has a verly low precedence when resolving overloads (largely for backwards compatibility).

Comment: umm... why would it choose println(String)? "intList.get(0)" has type Integer, and so naturally it chooses println(Object)

Comment: Yeah, I somehow got confused there. Should be fixed now.